# Rotating an OpenGL ES Object with GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, touch, rotation, glkit

I'm trying to rotate an OpenGL object in iOS using touch, but I'm having some trouble.  I am grabbing the user touches here:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    }

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
   {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
   dx = point.y - startPoint.y;
   dy = point.x - startPoint.x;
   startPoint = point;
   }
```

I'm using that in my update function to perform the rotation.  Right now I'm just trying to rotate left to right when I touch left to right and then front to back when I go up and down.  I get a weird combination rotation though.  Here's the code:

```
- (void)update
   {    
   float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
   GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

   self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

   GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.5f);
   modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, -1, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 0.0f);
   dx = dy =0;
   self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
   }
```

Comment: not sure how to do in GLK, but are you translating it to the origin before you rotate it (And back after) ?

Comment: No, I don't think I'm doing that.  The object isn't moving off of the screen, it is rotating, just not how I want it to.  Should I be doing that?

Comment: in OpenGL, you first translate (=slide) the object to the origin (0,0,0), then you rotate it, and then you translate it back to the it's supposed position. OpenGL always rotates arround the origin, if you dont slide it to there, your object "orbits" the origin, but doesnt rotate as expected arround itself.

Comment: Note: If you e.g want only rotate arround the Y axis, it's enough to translate it to Y = 0 etc.. hope I could help you.

Comment: I'm already translating it to the origin actually.  GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.5f);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're telling it to rotate in both x and y :)

Try this :

```
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, startPoint.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

This will rotate startPoint.x radians around the x-axis.

You can rotate about any axis you want by changing the last 3 parameters (i.e. 0,1,0 would rotate about the y-axis, 1,1,0 would rotate about a axis 45° between the x and y.)

NB Thanks @Marcelo Cantos for the clarification :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I understand your reasoning and it makes sense.  I gave that a shot, but now it doesn't move at all.

Comment: I figured it out.  You were on the right track.I'm not sure exactly why what I had doesn't work still, but I found something that does work.

Rather than making both moves at the same time using GLKMatrix4Rotate(), I'm using GLKMatrix4RotateX() and GLKMatrix4RotateY().

Comment: Sorry, I've misread the method signature and got my axes / radians mixed up - sorry! See my edit for a better answer!

Comment: @deanWombourne: Your explanation is misleading. It gives the impression that, e.g., setting the last parameter to 1.0f would rotate startPoint.x around the x-axis *and* the z-axis (whatever that might entail). Rotations are always expressed around a single axis defined by an arbitrary vector. In this case, the axis of rotation happens to be aligned with the x-axis. If you *did* change the last argument to 1.0f, you would get a single rotation about the vector that is 45° between the x- and z-axes (not two rotations).

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos - Oh, I didn't think of it being read that way; I've edited my answer :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per deanWombourne, you're using `GLKMatrix4Rotate` incorrectly. When you perform:

```
GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, -1, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 0.0f);
```

You rotate -1 radians around the axis (startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 0.0f). It sounds more like you want to rotate startPoint.x radians around (1, 0, 0) and startPoint.y radians around (0, 1, 0). So, for example:

```
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, startPoint.x, 1.0f, 0.0f 0.0f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, startPoint.y, 0.0f, 1.0f 0.0f);
```

Or you probably want to divide startPoint.x and startPoint.y, because that'll be hyper-responsive to touches.

It'll also have some gimbal lock issues — essentially because if you rotate around x first then the y axis isn't necessarily where you think it is, and if you rotate around y first then the x axis isn't necessarily where you think it is. Is that something you're concerned about?

Comment: Thanks.  I see more clearly now.  I noticed the issue with startPoint being very responsive.  I am dividing it down.  I would like the model to move like your finger does.  If you move at an angle, I'd like it to rotate up and back.  My separated out code using RotateX and RotateY seems to operate that way.  I can't figure how to get it to stop snapping to your finger though.